# Classic "omit" function, similar code totally different typing results when written the usual way and when written with currying, what did I miss?

Tags: typescript, currying, type-parameter

Ok so I was trying to write a type-aware "omit" function.

After a long, long reading of stack-overflow I came up with the following solution that works (yay):

```js
const omit = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  Del extends keyof T,
  U = { [Key in Exclude<keyof T, Del>]: T[Key] }
> (obj: T, ...props: Del[]): U =>
    Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]): U => {
      for (const del of props) {
        if (del === key) {
          return acc;
        }
      }
      return { ...acc, [key]: value };
    }, {} as U);
```

And if I write `omit({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'a');` then tsc understands it very well:

[image: perfect type inference without currying]

But I prefer the functional-programming way of writing these sorts of things, with a function that takes the props to omit and then returns a function that will take an object and return it without the specified props (useful for composition).

So I tried writing it like so, it's almost the same code:

```js
const fpOmit = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  Del extends keyof T,
  U = { [Key in Exclude<keyof T, Del>]: T[Key] }
> (...props: Del[]) => (obj: T): U =>
    Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]): U => {
      for (const del of props) {
        if (del === key) {
          return acc;
        }
      }
      return { ...acc, [key]: value };
    }, {} as U);
```

There are no errors, no warnings, but this time calling `fpOmit('a')({ a: 1, b: 2 });` doesn't infer the expected type at all:

[image: Unexpected inferred type from tsc for the result of fpOmit]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please edit or supplement your images with plain text, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) for more info.  Also, for this to be a [mcve] do you mind removing the `U` generic type parameter?  [This code](https://tsplay.dev/mpDLBm) exhibits the same issue without it.

Comment: The text goes away when I trie to copy capste-it, I'll add the alts at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function is called, all of its type parameters must be specified; either manually by the caller (like `fn<MyObjType, MyKeyType>(...)`) or via *inference* from the arguments passed to the function (and, occasionally, contextually from the expected return type).

In your original `omit()` function:

```
declare const omit: <T extends Record<string, unknown>, D extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, ...props: D[]
) => { [K in Exclude<keyof T, D>]: T[K]; }
```

the compiler can infer both the `T` and `D` type parameters from the `obj` and `props` arguments, and everything works out well:

```
const result = omit({ a: 1, b: 2 }, "a");
// const result: {  b: number; }
```

But in your curried version:

```
declare const fpOmit: <T extends Record<string, unknown>, D extends keyof T>(
    ...props: D[]) => (obj: T) => { [K in Exclude<keyof T, D>]: T[K]; }
```

while you are writing the following on one line:

```
const fpResult = fpOmit('a')({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

it's still a pair of function calls, like this:

```
const omitA = fpOmit('a');
const fpResult = omitA({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

And when you call `fpOmit('a')`, both of its type parameters `T` and `D` must be specified.  But while the compiler can infer `D` from the `'a'` input, it has no idea at all what to infer for `T`, and thus falls back to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
const omitA = fpOmit('a');
// const fpOmit: <Record<string, unknown>, "a">(
//   ...props: "a"[]) => (obj: Record<string, unknown>) => 
//  { [x: string]: unknown; }

// const omitA: (obj: Record<string, unknown>) => { [x: string]: unknown; }
```

And once that happens, it's all over.  The return type of `omitA()` does not depend on the type of the object passed into it; it's just `{ [x: string]: unknown; }` no matter what:

```
const fpResult = omitA({ a: 1, b: 2 });
// const fpResult2: { [x: string]: unknown; }
```

So we can't do it this way.

---

What you need to do instead is change the *scope* of your generic type parameters so that they only need to be specified when there is enough information available to do so.  So the `T` parameter needs to be moved to the call signature of the function *returned* by `fpOmit()`.  This also means you have to rephrase your constraints; you have to express `T` in terms of `D` and not vice versa:

```
declare const fpOmit: <D extends PropertyKey>(
    ...props: D[]) => <T extends Record<D, unknown>>(
        obj: T) => { [K in Exclude<keyof T, D>]: T[K]; }
```

Now everything works:

```
const fpResult = fpOmit('a')({ a: 1, b: 2 });
// const fpResult: { b: number; }
```

If you break it apart as before, you can see why:

```
const omitA = fpOmit('a');
// const fpOmit: <"a">(
//   ...props: "a"[]) => <T>(obj: T) => 
//   { [K in Exclude<keyof T, "a">]: T[K]; }

// const omitA: <T extends Record<"a", unknown>>(
//   obj: T) => { [K in Exclude<keyof T, "a">]: T[K]; }
```

The function returned from `fpResult()` is still generic in the type `T` of `obj`, and so the return type of `omitA()` will depend on that type:

```
const fpResult2 = omitA({ a: 1, b: 2 });
// const fpResult2: { b: number }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.5#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARC8A2IBOEAmSA3gLABQZZSVSe6WuS8A9sFAC5JNgCWbAXEgA8AFSQQAHmwjA8UJACV0TbHkHts3YAHMANEgCuwANbAmAd2AA+PSjGTpspEYgBPJgDMkwywApK1AKYAIwArAWE9ADpomGwmGCgBFABtAF1-KgBKJABeSyIkZIBpJE0kAFFxTH1aQWc3TwjUS1Tw4tSAbiQAXwpSAOZWDlwofQwOHM4eNh9CJBABAEY9IIEAJh69ACIQLcyOjKQAeiPGFnYkEbH+AqRVpGB9MCCIbC7e8n7qWkwcZEGLu4YAB5aYCER2KQyOSKZgqNRsDTaPSGEzmKw2SEOOT1DxeXyHALRSKxeKJVBpbJ5JA+YJhLxU-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-qququ7aoeSAbHDfTvqQ4XQHAiBIAA4kwTDxYc54Rt+JUAXIAAKqGvGwLhFK4VUoWSSSFnk6UQlBWVASg+WJlYCGlgyRbfUgbUdQRGhEXSJFkQNQ0vSNrhMR9k0ceJN3cbxPj8RAglLTVe3G+tMlbQpMEuDbtv3cd2lnRdrs-fLt2rYZJkneZ0TDfRb0CONyDdF7a2-S5bkFCyXkclyPINJDzTQ7DQaJeeZqypMfpKhjGpzHuB73HjOekITZDE5FZNoL8ZGcQjVA-PQ-xIylvDgoz0Gs-E7Oc9zfirdVfPoXWwulYBOWqOL1YTuml2IbL1Ieay7I+dy5X8oFMPCp2tPd-nqNFzMJdY-uOq4yFDZJZKF4oze9yPM8rzHxmn7TD6hc95fQMMcezGgvuCVMK9qCGmzLzNCBZ6r5BENLekwgpxAy3qDVOe9ti7APu0L+p5H59m3OCP8s8YTz0EKmCWNZLDIKaobdBycd5pz5DgtMWcj6vhPqA5+645Rbh3GXbGld74ZhAclM+14ChvyeC8Oatca5AA)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks, I still would have expected the compiler to warn me that I was writing bullshit