# Typescript complaining when I rewrite a generic 3 arity function as a curried version

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, currying

Hi and first off thanks to anyone taking the time to read this.

### Background

I have a function called "normalFunc" in typescript like such:

```ts
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/TaskEither';
import { User } from './some-api-library';

// Next function is just a dummy version of an actual api function we have. I added to make the type defs clear.
const searchById = (id: string): Promise<User | null> => Promise.resolve(null)

// The actual function I'm interested in
const normalFunc = <I, O, E>(eFn: (e: unknown) => E, lp: (id1: I) => Promise<O | null>, id2: I) => TE.tryCatch(() => lp(id2), eFn)
```

Notice normalFunc is a regular arity 3 function, no big deal here. It takes a function that will return some value to signify an error, then a function which takes a string and returns a promise that can return a nullable, and finally some value that will later be used as the input for the previous function that returns the promise.

I can use like so:

```ts
const testnormal = normalFunc(e => Error(`${e}`), searchById, '0001');
```

Typescript understands and resolves the generic types <I, O, E> just fine.

### The problem:

If I try to write normalFunc as a curried function:

```ts
// Notice this is function is typed exactly the same as the normal version, at least it looks like it to me.
// I actually copied the normal version and just changed a few characters to add the arrows and some necessary parenthesis.
const curriedFunc = <I, O, E>(eFn: (e: unknown) => E) => (lp: (id1: I) => Promise<O | null>) => (id2: I) => TE.tryCatch(() => lp(id2), eFn)
```

Perhaps it is easier to read if I rearrange it like this:

```ts
// Same function as above but nicer format
const curriedFunc = <I, O, E>(eFn: (e: unknown) => E) =>
                               (lp: (id1: I) => Promise<O | null>) =>
                                 (id2: I) =>
                                   TE.tryCatch(() => lp(id2), eFn)
```

This time when I try to use it, I get a typescript error in the second arity/function call in the chain:

```ts
const testCurried = curriedFunc(e => Error(`${e}`))(searchById)('0001');

// Typescript complains (highlights) the second function call in the chain (searchById)
// It says that:
//   Argument of type '(id: string) => Promise<User | null>' is not assignable to
//   parameter of type '(id1: unknown) => Promise<unknown>'.
//     Types of parameters 'id' and 'id1' are incompatible.
//       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I'm still completely baffled by this error. Perhaps generic functions using multiple arrows for currying need a different syntax? Typescript didn't seem to mind when I rewrote the normal function to make it curried with my use of the generic types <I, O, E>. But I don't understand why the types don;t seem to check anymore if the function is almost identical except for the curried rewrite.

If anyone has any idea of what is happening here I'll deeply appreciate it.

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624500/2887218) to the question this duplicates for more information.  You need to change the scope of your type parameters so that there are actual inference sites for them upon the function call.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjJ88w), except I can't test it because your example here relies on third-party libraries not present in a standalone IDE.

Comment: @jcalz is spot on, as usual. I did manage to stub out the types for the playground though, so here's a 100% working example: https://tsplay.dev/WGkdXW